# How to handle failed subscription-payments with cashier?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using cashier 12.1 with stripe. I have created a daily billing price plan and subscribed for a user. After creating subscription I changed the  default card to 4100000000000019 to test fraudulent transaction. In next billing cycle transaction is blocked in stripe but according to cashier subscription table this subscription is still active . Why it like that? Is there anything else I should do to track transactions from stripe and make the corresponding changes in cashier table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be defining a webhook handler for such use case.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#defining-webhook-event-handlers

Some potential events could listen to for your case are `customer.subscription.updated` and `invoice.payment_failed`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have a confusion. There is already  Laravel\Cashier\Http\Controllers\WebhookController  with 'handleCustomerSubscriptionUpdated ' function ,provided  by cashier package. Does it able to handle the problem of 'blocked or invaild card?

Comment: It doesn't exactly handle it per se. You have to extract the error in the payload to actually see if a payment has failed due to invalid card, etc. Refer to https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes#card-declined for full info, including bank decline codes.